# Additional term in energy-stress tensor for classical gravity

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, newtonian-gravity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Consider a flat Minkowski space. Given is the field $\phi = \phi(t,\vec{x})$ and the Lagrangian with minimal coupling to matter $$L(\phi, \partial_\mu \phi) = \frac{1}{8\pi G} \partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu\phi + \phi \rho$$
I aim to derive the energy-stress tensor which should take the form
$$T^{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{4\pi G}(\partial^\mu\phi\partial^\nu\phi - \frac{1}{2}\eta^{\mu\nu}\partial_\alpha\phi\partial^\alpha\phi)\ . $$

However, when deriving it, I obtain an additional term reading
$$-\eta^{\mu\nu}\rho\phi$$
, arising from the second term in the definition of the energy-stress tensor
$$T^{\mu\nu} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)}\partial^\nu\phi - \eta^{\mu\nu}L\ .$$

Why does it vanish?

Comment: Why do you think the stress-energy tensor should take that particular form?

Comment: Since it's given in the excerice as a solution. Actually, only the $T^{ij}$ components are given but it shouldn't make a difference. There are also no further assumptions made on the density, on the contrary, later the Poisson equation with $\rho \neq 0$ is used to derive to contribution to the Navier-Stokes equation.